# Is there a way I can create a Path or Curve to use for TubeGeomety(path,...) from an existing geometry's points/vertices array?

Tags: three.js

I'm very new to both three.js & to js in general.
1st I select a polyHedron geometry with a dat.gui checkbox
which renders say a tetrahedron. these selections work.
I also have a dat.gui checkbox to either phongfill or wireframe render. 
I initially wanted just a wireframe type mesh but not with all of the internal triangles. I found the edgesgeometry() function which draws pretty much what I want(hard edges only). there is however a known issue with linewidth not working in windows anymore. all lines drawn as strokeweight/width 1.

I'd like to use tubeGeometry() to draw tubes of whatever radius as opposed to 1weight lines. I know I'll have to draw something such as a sphere at/over the connection vertices for it to not look ridiculous.

```
geo = new THREE.TetrahedronBufferGeometry(controls0.Radius,controls0.Detail);
...
egeo = new THREE.EdgesGeometry( geo );
lmat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0x0099ff, linewidth: 4 });
ph = new THREE.LineSegments( egeo, lmat );
scene.add(ph);
....
```

playing around in the console I found some geometry/bufferGeomery arrays that are likely the vertices/indices of my selected X-hedron as their sizes change with type(tetra/icosa etc) selection & detail increase/decrease:

```
//p = dome.geometry.attributes.uv.array;
p = egeo.attributes.position.array
//p = geo.attributes.uv.array
...
var path = new THREE.Curve();
path.getPoint = function (t) {
// trace the arc as t ranges from 0 to 1
var segment = (0 - Math.PI*2) *t;
return new THREE.Vector3( Math.cos(segment), Math.sin(segment), 0);
};

 var geomet = new THREE.TubeBufferGeometry( path, 10, 0.2, 12, false );
 var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geomet, mat );
 scene.add( mesh );
```

from above the tubeGeometry() draws fine separately as well but with the "path" made by that curve example. How can I use the vertices from my tetrahedron for example to create that "path" to pass to tubegeometry() ?

maybe a function that creates "segment vectors" from the vertices ? 
I think it needs other properties of curve/path as well ?
I'm quite stuck at this point.

ANY Help, suggestions or examples would be greatly appreciated !
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create a `TubeGeometry` for each edge. Generate a `LineCurve3` as the input path. Use the vertices of the edge as the start and end vector for the line.

Consider to use something like "triangulated lines" as an alternative in order to visualize the wireframe of a mesh with a `linewidth` greater than 1. With the next release of `three.js`(`R91`) there are new line primitives for this. Demo:

https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/dev/examples/webgl_lines_fat.html

This approach is much more performant than drawing a bunch of meshes with a `TubeGeometry`.